# Optical lense distance from an object

Tags: raspberry-pi, computer-vision

I am using a Raspberry PI camera and the problem in hand is how to find the best position for it in order to fully see an object.

The object looks like this:

[image]

Question is how to find the perfect position given that the camera is placed in the centre of the above image. Perfectly the camera will be able to catch the object only, as the idea is to get the camera as close as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a picture with you camera, save it as a JPG, then open it in a viewer that allows you to inspect the EXIF header. If you are lucky you should see the focal length (in mm) and the sensor size. If the latter is missing, you can probably work it out from the sensor's spec sheet (see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) to start). From the two quantities you can work out the angle of the field of view (HorizFOV = atan(0.5 * sensor_width / focal_length), VertFOV = atan(0.5 * sensor_height / focal_length). From these angles you can derive an approximate distance from your subject that will keep it fully in view.

Note that these are only approximations. Nonlinear lens distortion will produce a slightly larger effective FOV, especially near the corners.